# Force replace-on-reboot in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is there a flag in Inno Setup to *require* a file be replaced on reboot?  The conventional 'restartreplace' flag only replaces on reboot if Inno deems it necessary (i.e. if the file is in-use and cannot be directly copied).

Alternatively, is there a flag to require that a file never be replaced on reboot, but will *not* display an error message on failure?  If 'restartreplace' isn't passed, and the file is in-use, Inno will display an error message.  Is there any way to change this behavior?

Basically, my question is:  is there any way to separate the "two-step" logic that is usually present in 'restartreplace' (try direct copy, then either error or try replace-on-reboot)?

Thank you!